# React table v7 dynamic filtering/sorting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I have a column in my react table v7 that the filtering that doesn't work because the accessor is basing it on my data, I want to still be able to search for "Not approved" when I input it on my ColumnFilter. the value of not approved only shows when the approvedBy in the data is null.

```
      {
        Header: 'Approved By',
        accessor: 'approvedBy.fname',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
        disableSortBy: true,
        Cell: e => {
          return (
            <>
              {e.row.original.approvedBy ? (
                `${e.row.original.approvedBy.fname} ${e.row.original.approvedBy.lname}`
              ) : (
                <Tag colorScheme="red">Not Approved</Tag>
              )}
            </>
          );
        },
      },
```

This is my column filter component.

```
function GlobalFilter({ column }) {
  const { filterValue, setFilter } = column;
  return (
    <Box>
      <Input
        my="1rem"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={filterValue || ''}
        onChange={e => setFilter(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it -- you'll have to [implement your own `filter`](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters#column-options) to filter the way you want. I implemented one for a very similar use case in a project as well.

That, or you could mutate your `data` array to replace a falsy `approvedBy` value with "Not Approved", and truthy ones with "{fname} {lname}". This would mean react-table is now actually looking at the data you want it to be looking at, instead of an Object or `false`. It might also be inconvenient to implement, depending on how your data is structured.